# How to retrieve a sum of table column in play java framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am new in play  and I am able to retrieve all column in database but i don't know how to get a sum of all retrieve data

[model class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiOpx.png)

[controller class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN0Ar.png)

Comment: What do you mean by *sum of all retrieve* data? BTW if you provide code it should be in a text-form as part of the question, not as a screenshot

Comment: I mean : the addition of the column

Comment: what i what to know is to do sothing like this but in java :                         SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;

Comment: Okay, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want to get the sum of all `amount` fields of your `General_store` model in Java you can define a method to calculate it:

```
private static long sumOfStores() {
    long sum = 0;
    List<General_store> allStores = General_store.all();
    for (General_store gs : allStores) {
        sum += gs.amount;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Of course if you are using Java 8 you can use a stream.

But the more important part is this: DON'T DO THAT IN ANY CASE. The reason is that this is information which is stored in the database. So you should ask the database for any aggregation on this information that is rather trivial to compute. In the case of `SUM` this is really trivial. With the above approach you will first fetch ALL items from the database only to perform some trivial operation on one of  their fields. So please use `SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;` and save yourself the troubles. With Ebean you can use such queries without a problem:

```
private static long sumOfStores() {
    final String sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM General_store";

    SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
    SqlRow row = sqlQuery.findUnique();
    return row.getLong("total");
}
```

Comment: Great idea thanks . be patient and i ask one more question , now i am trying to print the result through my controller but i get an error plz help :                 `public static Result ShowBalance( ) {
        Form<General_store> taskData = form(General_store.class);

        return ok   (views.html.balance.render(General_store.sumOfStores(), taskData)
        );}    `

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you might consider accepting it. Just FYI: open another question if you have a different problem instead of editing this one :) I will try to help there as well

Comment: error says that can not applied to lon.play.form<models.General_store>

Comment: I would **really suggest to open a new question** as this is now related to the Play templating engine. Include the code for `balance.scala.html` - it seems like the template has the wrong parameters or maybe even the form creation is wrong. Also which Play version are you using? 2.1?